# Python regex not matching all patterns in string

Tags: python, regex

I want to match a curl command's header pattern like:

> -H 'key: value'

or

> -H "key: value"

This switch can appear in the middle somewhere or at the end of string.

My pattern:

```
>>> header_pattern = re.compile(' \-H (?:\'|\").+?:.+?(?:\'|\")(?:\s+|$)')
```

My string:

```
>>> a = " -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxx' -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' "
```

Now I attempted to find all instances of this pattern but its matching just the first pattern.

```
>>> headers = header_pattern.findall(a)
>>> headers
[" -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxx' "]
```

Comment: Yes because your pattern matches a space at the end and at the beginning. Change `(?:\s+|$)` to `(?!\S)` *(not followed by a character that is not a whitespace)*

Comment: `(?:-H|\G)\s([\'"])[^\'"]+\1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't use [`argparse` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) instead of regular expressions:

```
import argparse
import shlex


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('command')
parser.add_argument('url')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--data')
parser.add_argument('-b', '--data-binary', default=None)
parser.add_argument('-H', '--header', action='append', default=[])
parser.add_argument('--compressed', action='store_true')


curl_command = "curl https://google.com  -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxx' -H 'Content-Type: text/plain'"

tokens = shlex.split(curl_command)
parsed_args = parser.parse_args(tokens)
print(parsed_args.header)
```

Prints `['Authorization: Bearer xxx', 'Content-Type: text/plain']`.

(Inspired by [`uncurl` package](https://github.com/spulec/uncurl)).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Though this is not answer to question's concern but really gives me a lot better approach to achieve what I am trying to do.!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex to match all header options:

```
header_pattern = re.compile(r'-H\s*([\'"])(.+?)\1')
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qD7eY0/2)

There is no real need to assert for whitespace before `-H` but you need you can use:

```
header_pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=\s)-H\s*([\'"])(.+?)\1')
```